How can I disable redoc url in My application FastAPI documentation?
I have used FastAPI to develop some APIs but in the product environment, I want to disable redoc so that users can't see the APIs list.
I have overridden the redoc endpoint in my API but it is still coming. How can I fix it?

You can disable redoc by this code:
app = FastAPI(redoc_url=None)

Also, you could determine is it production or development stage by env variable in settings:
from pydantic import BaseSettings
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    environment: str = "development"
    class Config:
        env_file = ".env"

settings = Settings()

So in production you should change environment to production.
After this, you can disable redoc by this env:
app = FastAPI(redoc_url=None if settings.environment == "production" else "/redoc")

